# What is a is lowercase alphabetic KeySym on a Ubuntu Keyboard?

Tags: key, definition, lowercase, alphabetic

I am working with keysyms of a Linux Keyboard and need to consider the following rule:

*The Shift modifier is off, and the Lock modifier is on and is interpreted as CapsLock. In this case, the first KeySym is used, but if that KeySym is **lowercase alphabetic**, then the corresponding uppercase KeySym is used instead.*

On a Keyboard I might have **Ä-ä, Ö-ö, Ü-ü** on a German Keyboard or **ù-%** on a French keyboard.

- what is the definition of an alphabetic key?
- Are ä , ö, ü, ù considered lowercase alphabetic?
- Is an alphabetic key only a-z, A-Z or are the special characters (ä , ö, ü, ù ) included?